# why is not possible to mock Pattern.class in jmock?

Tags: java, jmock

I am trying to create some unit test but I realized I cannot mock `Pattern.class` using jmock.

I get an error saying

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.regex.Pattern is not an interface
```

Everytime I try to do something like this

```
final Pattern mockedPattern = mockery.mock(Pattern.class);
```

Checking on the internet I saw could be because this is a singleton bean and there is no way to mock it.

Is there any workaround to mock it? or any way to test it?

Cheers.

EDIT----

Basically, I used this answer [How to disable CSRF in Spring Security 4 only for specific URL pattern through XML configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960810/how-to-disable-csrf-in-spring-security-4-only-for-specific-url-pattern-through-x) and it works great but I need to create the unit test for it

```
 private Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");
    private RegexRequestMatcher unprotectedMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("/ext/**", null);

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {          
        if(allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches()){
            return false;
        }
        return !unprotectedMatcher.matches(request);
    }
```

Comment: the code where you are trying to mock is still missing in the question

Comment: thanks @nullpointer, Ive updated it, please take a look

Comment: why do you want to mock `Pattern`???

Comment: Im making a test where I mocked the class (that implements RequestMatcher) and it has one method "matches" that calls pattern, so, I need to make a expectation of this pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you should mock the request to test the code you posted, not `Pattern`:

```
MockHttpServletRequest req1 = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", "/foobar");
assertThat(theThing.matches(req1)).isFalse();
// ...
```

See [`MockHttpServletRequest`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html#MockHttpServletRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: what exactly is "theThing" ?

Comment: the instance of the class where you have your `public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request)`, you didn't specify its name, so..